# Delete portion of characters from each line in notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I am trying to delete range of characters from each line in notepad

input:

> - 0   0000    Stringxx1   DescribeString1
> - 1   0001    Stringxx2   DescribeString2.

output:

> - Stringxx1
> - Stringxx2

I've gone through [this](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Regular_Expressions)

I could just select the String with spaces however not sure how to proceed further. Note the words starts with String however can be of varying length.

> \sString.*?\s

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
^.*?(String\S*).*
```

And replace with `$1`.

**Explanation:**

- `^` - start of string
- `.*?` - zero or more characters other than a newline but as few as possible before....
- `(String\S*)` - (Group 1) a literal character sequence `String` followed with zero or more characters other than whitespace (`\S*`)
- `.*` - zero or more characters other than a newline (up to the end of a line)

[image]

Comment: Thanks it worked ! Just a question regarding \S*
\S - indicates not a space
*  - indicates  matches 0 or more instances of the previous character

so combination of \S* indicates all 0 or more instances of "Not a space" characters?

Comment: I think I have explained that as *zero or more characters other than whitespace (`\S*`)* - yes, you are right. If you only need word characters (letters, digits and underscore), replace `\S` with `\w`.